# running code with threads in Octave

Tags: multithreading, matlab, octave

I have several blocks of the following code that each use there own matrix. Is there a way to run each block in it's own thread rather then run all of them sequentially?

```
for i=1:length(DJI)
DJI2(:,1) = reshape(datenum(strvcat(DJI(:,2)(:)), length(DJI(:,2)),'yyyy-mm-dd'));
DJI2(:,2:6) = reshape(str2num(strvcat(DJI(:,3:7)(:)), length(DJI(:,3:7))));
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to members on the Octave email list the only way to do this is with the following library.
http://atc.ugr.es/javier-bin/mpitb
It is designed to be used on multiple machines but looks like it can be used on an individual one as well.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was about Octave, but just to let you know, MATLAB provides this functionality via [PARFOR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/distcomp/parfor.html).

P.S. I'm confused by your code snippet, since the loop variable "i" doesn't actually appear in the loop anywhere.